# Separate a string,java with regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to separate a string but to keep separators except space.

Also I'd like to not separate words like `asda45a` or `asd6ad`.

this is the list of separators:

```
private static String delimits="[{;}(),#<>*+-=/ ]+";
```

I tried `String[] List = o.split("(?<="+delimits+")|(?="+delimits+")");`

Comment: Could you provide a sample of a full string you would use this on?

Comment: also what do you mean by `words like asda45a or asd6ad`?

Comment: Words with numbers,
I try to make a lexical analyzer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust your `delimits` pattern to exclude the space (since you do not want to keep space delimiters in the result) and put the `-` at the end  of the character class as in your expression it forms a range between `+` and `=`. Then, just add an `| +` alternative to the main regex:

```
String delimits="[{;}(),#<>*+=/-]+";
String o = "asda45a or-ro asd6ad";
String[] lst = o.split("(?<="+delimits+")|(?="+delimits+")| +");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lst));
// => [asda45a, or, -, ro, asd6ad]
```

See the [online Java demo](http://ideone.com/LDATOM)

If you want to split with any whitespace, replace `| +` with `|\\s+`.